# Image Button ID Conflict?

Tags: android, imagebutton

My app works when using a button, but when I try to use an Image Button I get a runtime exception "Unable to Start Activity.......ClassCastException: android:widget:button.

I set the button by ID in the java file like so

btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

Here is the ImageButton in the xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ball"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

My tried cleaning the project with no success.  What am I missing??

HelP!

Thanks In Advance

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is: `btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);`

Answer (score 0):

An ImageButton is **NOT** a Button. Meaning you cannot cast one to the other period.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a newb!  How do I make a button with an image that won't distort the image proportions??  button doesn't work!

Comment: A button has the ability to have a background: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background along with this it also has the ability to orient an image according to the text.

Comment: The problem is it orients and sizes to fit the text. I want it to fit the image.  A button works perfect except I can't get it to maintain the aspect ratio of the image!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[ImageButton extends ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Thanks to Android developers for this clear logic.

Comment: From the same category of fun-  Button extends TextView.  Which is why ImageButton can't extend Button-  because there's no text for a text view.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a newb! How do I make a button with an image that won't distort the image proportions?? button doesn't work! – user2088429